# For CW complexes X, Y where $X$ is $m$-connected, $Y$ is $n$-connected, $\pi_r[X\vee Y] =\pi_r[X\times Y]$ for all $r\lt m+n+1$ via inclusion.

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

It is known that if a CW complex $X$ has no cells in dim $\le k$, then it is $k-$ connected that is 1) X is path connected, 2) the homotopy groups $\pi_r(X)=0$ for all $r\le k$.

Suppose that the converse of the above statement is true and hence assume that $X$ has no cells in dim $\le m$ and that $Y$ has no cells in dim $\le n$. Then, the cellular structure of $X\times Y$ has no cells in dim $\le m+n$.  But I'm not sure how to go from here.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with your second paragraph: if $X$ has a cell in dimension $m+1$, then $X \times Y$ also has a cell in that dimension (the product of that cell and a $0$-cell in $Y$). Maybe I disagree with the premise in your very first sentence: having "no cells" below a certain dimension is not possible unless the CW complex is empty, because you always need $0$-cells.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: Thanks. I think I should have said: no cells of non zero dim <=k.

Comment: Each CW-complex has at least one cell in dimension 0.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, it's noted in the comments already.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Can you please explain what the cell structure of $X\times Y/X\vee Y$ is?

Comment: Note that $X \times Y/X \vee Y$ is the smash product of $X$ and $Y$. You can look up the cell structure of a smash product of CW-complexes, it is particularly simple because a smash product of spheres is a sphere.

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960601. In the last sentence you will an answer to your question. Wedge and product have the same skeleton up to a sufficiently high dimension.

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't think it answers my question. X and Y in my case may have more than 1 zero cell.

Comment: Every path-connected CW complex is homotopy equivalent to one with a single $0$-cell. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343777/every-cw-complex-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-cw-complex-with-1-0-cell and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454762/all-finite-path-connected-cw-complexes-are-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-cw-complex-w, for instance.

Comment: If $m, n \ge 1$ (which seems to be the only interesting case because otherwise you do not have any restriction), and if you are interested in the fundamental groups, then you only need to consider a single path component. And this only contains a single 0-cell.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible that a non-empty CW complex has no cells in dimension $\le k$; each non-empty CW complex must have a non-empty $0$-skeleton $X^0$.

Thus the first correction is to require that $X$ has no cells in dimension $r$ for $1 \le r \le k$. In particular, it does not have $1$-cells. Then, if $X$ has more than one $0$-cell, $X$ cannot be path connected. In fact, it is well-known that a CW complex is path-connected iff its $1$-skeleton is path-connected.

Therefore the correct statement is

> If a CW complex $X$ has one $0$-cell (i.e. $X^0 = *$) and no cells in dimensions $r$ with  $1 \le r \le k$ (i.e. $X^r = *$ for $r \le k$) then it is $k$- connected, that is the homotopy groups $\pi_r(X)=0$ for all $r\le k$.

Let us look at $X \vee Y$, where the wedge point is the single $0$-cell. $X \vee Y$ can be regarded as the subspace $X \times * \cup * \times Y$ of $X \times Y$. It has an obvious cellular structure; its $r$-cells are the products $e_X^r \times *$ and $* \times e_Y^r$, where the $e_X^r$ and $e_Y^r$ are the $r$-cells of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Thus the $r$-skeleton of $X \vee Y$ is

$$(X \vee Y)^r = X^r \times * \cup * \times Y^r .$$

Also $X \times Y$ has an obvious cellular structure. Its $r$-cells are the products $e_X^i \times e_Y^j$ with $i + j = r$, where the $e_X^i$ and $e_Y^j$ are the $i$-cells of $X$ and $j$-cells of $Y$, respectively. Clearly
all $e_X^r \times *$ and $* \times e_Y^r$ are $r$-cells of $X \times Y$. Let us call an $r$-cell $e_X^i \times e_Y^j$ (where $i + j = r$) *non-trivial* if $i > 0$ and $j > 0$. A necessary requirement for the existence of a non-trivial $r$-cell is that $i > m$ and $j > n$ because $X$ does not have $i$-cells for $1 \le i \le m$ and $Y$ does not have $j$-cells for $1 \le i \le n$. Hence there are no non-trivial $r$-cells for $1 \le r \le m + n +1$. This means that

$$(X \times Y)^{m+n+1} =  X^{m+n+1}  \times * \cup *  \times Y^{m+n+1} = (X \vee Y)^{m+n+1}.$$

By cellular approximation we see that the inclusion-induced
$$\pi_r(X \vee Y) \to \pi_rf(X \times Y)$$
is an isomorphism for all $r < m+n+1$.